# Granted admission on WB instead of B1/B2, Denied Correction by CBP

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, us-visa-waiver-program

Hoping someone can help me here, Just trying to find out what options I have.

I first travelled to America on a WB in Aug 2018 and left in Nov 2018. While back in Australia (my home country) I applied for a B1/B2 visa which I was granted as my work required me to stay longer for training and to attend a trade show for my next visit! I then re-entered America in Jan 2019, however was granted admission under my previous WB (Visa Waiver) instead of my new B1/B2 visa, as I had been booked for training and trade shows for a full 6 months I attended the local CBP Deferred Inspections site to request they change the status from WB to B1/B2 which I was denied- My problem is now I am required to finish my training of an affiliate companies clients as well as attend the trade shows as planned but am required to now exit the country by Apr 2019!

Am I able to go to Canada or Mexico for a week and then re-enter on my B1/B2 before Apr 2019 instead of the WB thus extending my time?

Or will I have to fly home and then try my luck flying back into America to re-enter on a B1/B2 that way,

Either way I’m aware there’s a good chance I could be refused.

Any options would help me greatly as I’m getting quite a lot of stress from my work in Australia and the requirements I have to complete in America.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could spend a weekend in Costa Rica.

Comment: What grounds did they give you for denying the correction of your admission record?

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen I don't see why Canada or Mexico is out.  The traveler ought to be able to be admitted in B-1 status despite the existence of a recent WB admission.  I don't see anything on the page you link to that suggests otherwise.  Did I overlook something?

Comment: That I should have spoken to the immigration officer whilst in the airport before exiting the federal inspection zone! Of course due to the government shutdown it made things hard, that’s why I only went to the CBP office recently

Comment: That's crazy.  One purpose for [deferred inspection](https://www.cbp.gov/contact/deferred-inspection/overview-deferred-inspection) is "to review and issue the necessary documents to remedy errors recorded on arrival documents issued at the time of entry to the United States relating to improper non-immigrant classification, inaccurate biographical information or incorrect period of admission." Why have such a facility if people who don't notice the mistake right away aren't allowed to use it?  People who *do* notice right away won't *need* to use it.  When did you actually notice the mistake?

Comment: @phoog Practice is they won't correct anything that isn't beyond the traveller's control. OP not presenting the passport open at the visa page (to make it clear they wish to use a visa) is considered to be within their control, and so the deferred inspection stations won't help with that unless an individual officer decides to out of good will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an update to help anyone in the future reading this -

I flew to Costa Rica over the weekend and re-entered US, making sure to give the immigration officer my passport held open to the B1/B2 Visa page and was granted 6-months no problem :D

Comment: And it would've ended no differently if you had taken a bus/train to Canada/Mexico. Enjoy your stay :)

Answer (score 6):

In the future, if using a visa don't hand over your passport closed, or open at the main ID page, but at the visa page.

You can exit for Canada/Mexico and re-enter, explaining the purpose for the border hop. Provided you can justify your purpose for entering on the visa, you'll be fine.

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted?

Comment: @Crazydre I'm not sure the a border hop to Mexico/Canada would work after further research as it still is calculated onto my time, So Costa Rica may be the way to go, however wont i have to prove why i was there? surely if i say due to the visa issue this would be classed as some sort of fraud against the system

Comment: @SMac It's only counted onto the time if you re-enter under the VWP. Like I said, open the passport at the visa page and they'll know you wish to enter in B2 status, and if they ask why you didn't the first time, just say you made the mistake of not opening the passport at the visa page whereby the CBP officer didn't realise you wish to enter in B2 status, while the deferred inspection station refused to correct it. TLDR: you're making this situation sound twisted and horrible - it's not; you'll be just fine if taking the steps I described!